# Minimum number of generators of product ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, let $I, J \subseteq k[x_1,\dots, x_n, y_1,\dots, y_m]$ be ideals such that the polynomials in $I$ depend only on $x_1,\dots, x_n$ and the polynomials in $J$ depend only on $y_1,\dots, y_m$, and let $i, j$ be the minimum number of generators of $I$ and $J$, respectively. Is the minimum number of generators of the product ideal $IJ \subseteq k[x_1,\dots, x_n, y_1,\dots, y_m]$ equal to $i j$?

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it didn't actually address the question, but it might be good to clarify what you mean by the notation $IJ$; is it the ideal generated by products of elements of the images of $I$ and $J$ under the canonical inclusions of rings?

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for the feedback, I have clarified my question.